# Merge multiple records into one record owned by a person?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, consolidation

How do I turn the following:

```
username | userLastFirst    | email             | approver1         |department
FAlbert  | Albert, Frankie  | abc123@ships.com  | Doe, John         |HR
FAlbert  | Albert, Frankie  | abc123@ships.com  | Smith, Mike       |HR
```

Into this:

```
username | userLastFirst    | email             | approver1    |approver2   |department
FAlbert  | Albert, Frankie  | abc123@ships.com  | Doe, John    |Smith, Mike |HR
```

Instead of multiple rows of the same user with their approvers, I'm looking to consolidate it into one record with columns of their approvers.

Comment: And what if they have 3 approvers, or more?

Comment: Only the first three would be shown.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two rows, you can use aggregation:

```
select username, userLastFirst, email, min(approver) as approver1 ,
       nullif(max(approver), min(approver)) as approver2, department
from t
group by username, userLastFirst, email, department;
```

Comment: What if I have three approvers?

Comment: @VincentLuc . . . You would get two of them.  If you wanted all three, you would have a different question -- your desired results here clearly have only two columns for approvers  You should ask *new* questions as a *new* question.